# Comment traduire "schon heute" / "bereits heute" ?

Tags: traduction, indications-de-temps, allemand

Dans la phrase

> Wir sichern Ihnen schon heute eine professionelle und gewissenhafte
>   Bearbeitung des Projektes zu.

comment puis-je traduire "schon heute" / "bereits heute" (already today in English).

Voici mes efforts:

> Nous vous promettons un traitement professionnel et consciencieux du
>   projet aujourd'hui déjà.

Si j'utilise *à partir d'aujourd'hui*, ça serait mieux ?
Je pense que si j'utilise ça, la phrase n'aurait plus le même sens, n'est-ce pas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Je pense que l'expression la plus courante pour exprimer cela en français est *dès aujourd'hui*.

> Nous vous promettons un traitement professionnel et soigné du projet dès aujourd'hui.

De la même façon « *schon jetzt* » deviendrait « dès maintenant ». L'idée qui se cache derrière ces expressions françaises c'est : « pas besoin d'attendre ! »

« À partir d'aujourd'hui » signifierait que le service est nouveau et qu'aujourd'hui est la première date où il est disponible (*ab heute*). Ni « *aujourd'hui déjà » ni « *déjà aujourd'hui » ne sont employés en français.

Comment: Variante pas géniale mais un peu plus proche du texte : "Nous vous promettons dès maintenant une prestation [de qualité] professionnelle et scrupuleuse dans ce projet"